# Android - C# equivalent to Volley?

Tags: java, c#, android

Question was too broad so I'm fixing that up a bit:

How can I efficiently handle REST requests in Unity3D.

Comment: The question is a bit to broad. Does the data need to be sent back and forth (like in an co-op or multiplayer game)? Then you'll have to keep permanent connections open. Is it only to save the game progress? Create a REST or Webservice in Java and connect there (i.e. using an AuthToken you receive during first login). Anyways. since it's to broad of a question, it's not appropriate for StackOverflow. Please only questions to **one specific problem** you have

Comment: @Tseng - I'll attempt to reword the question to be more specific, however this question is not for Java (See title). This also is not a game, think of it more like if I was creating a facebook application.  It's as simple as needing to communicate with the database and get database results, using C#.

Comment: is there something inefficient with the standard way?